# Rewrite sub directory from main domain with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website and I made the main domain in my example www.myweb.com, but I want to create a website again on the website with a different source example www.myweb.com/mychild I have tried but can not access because there is a conflict in .httaccess main domain, is there something you need to change for the htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html|pdf|woff|ttf|eot|svg)$ index.php
```

Directory Map

```
Application
Asset
public
mychild **#here I want to make a website access for his child**
resources
vendor
```

Comment: Well, you need to add an exception for requests to that folder which gets applied prior the to existing final rule.

Comment: Besides: why is this question tagged `php`?

Comment: Thanks @arkascha any sample? i using `php` tag because my web using php :)

Comment: Rewriting requests on level of the http server is completely independent from the application logic you use. The `php` tag does not belong here, the question does not somehow depend on the fact that you are using php elsewhere.